# How to disable Downloadify

Tags: javascript, flash

I am using Downloadify exactly as explained at http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html  and with a paragraph element with id="downloadify", but I want to conditionally disable the downloadify button.

How do I make the call to disable?

Comment: Was my answer of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Downloadify has `disable` method, so something along that might help you.

```
var downloadify = $("#downloadify").downloadify( options );
downloadify.disable();
// to enable again
downloadify.enable();
```

Source in [Github](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify/blob/master/src/downloadify.js#L135).